# Visual studio SQL | Server Project | SQL files syntax verification

Tags: sql, visual-studio-2012, configuration, migration

We recently migrated our project from VS2008 to VS2012. We had a project DataBase project wich just contains sql files.
When I migrated the solution, I migrated this project to a SQL Server project.

Problem :

- When I compile the VS2012 solution, SQL files syntax is checked and a
  lot of errors are displayed.

What I tried :

- Setup the solution so that DataBase Project is not build : syntax
  errors are still displayed.
- In properties of each SQL file, set
  "Extended T-SQL Warnings" to false : syntax errors are not displayed
  anymore but **I don't want to ask my team to set it each time they
  create a sql file**.

What is the best solution ? Would be very grateful.

Comment: or your could fix the syntax errors, instead of just pretending they're not there?

Comment: These scripts run well on SQL Server

Answer (score 0):

An old question, but to help anyone looking for something similar:

I am using a database project just to hold my SQL files in a solution, but don't want to use the built in Microsoft deployment mechanisms as I have rolled my own. I get lots of Error 70001's on drop and recreate statements within my procedures. To fix this, set Build Action in the file properties to "None".

(Specifically, in the Visual Studio solution explorer, select your file and in the "File Properties" panel, change the "Build Action" value to "None")

To create a template to do the same to avoid each user having to set it each time, see the following StackOverflow entry: 
[How Do I Make a VS2013 SQL Script Item Template With Default Build Action = None](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29085374/how-do-i-make-a-vs2013-sql-script-item-template-with-default-build-action-none)

Comment: Could you please elaborate more your answer adding a little more description about the solution you provide?