# How Do I Make a VS2013 SQL Script Item Template With Default Build Action = None

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I want to make an item template that works with Visual Studio 2013 such that when I right-click and select **Add** -> **New Item** I am able to choose my script template from the available selection, add it to my project with the template content, and have the default build action set to None automatically.

I am able to create an item template that will work and it will have the default content but I am unable to have the default build action be set to None (it is always set to Build).

I was able to get this working in Visual Studio 2010 and Visual Studio 2012 using the WizardExtension and WizardData directives below inside the .vstemplate file, but either I'm doing it wrong or it's no longer supported in Visual Studio 2013.

Example of what I used in VS2012 .vstemplate file:

> < WizardExtension>
>
> < Assembly>Microsoft.VisualStudio.Data.Tools.Package, Version=11.1.0.0, Culture=Neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a,
>    Custom=null< /Assembly>
>
> < FullClassName>Microsoft.VisualStudio.Data.Tools.Package.Project.TemplateWizard< /FullClassName>
>
> < /WizardExtension>
>
> < WizardData>
>
> < BuildAction>None< /BuildAction>
>
> < ItemAttributes>< /ItemAttributes>
>
> < /WizardData>

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You need to update the assembly version to 12.0.0.0

```
<WizardExtension>
  <Assembly>Microsoft.VisualStudio.Data.Tools.Package, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=Neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, Custom=null</Assembly>     
  <FullClassName>Microsoft.VisualStudio.Data.Tools.Package.Project.TemplateWizard</FullClassName>
</WizardExtension>
<WizardData>
    <BuildAction>None</BuildAction>
    <ItemAttributes></ItemAttributes>
</WizardData>
```

Comment: I just tried that and it worked!  I'm glad it was something simple